# Finding the number of links associated with a downloadable product

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, downloadable

I am working on a Magento CE 1.7.0.2 site that contains Downloadable Products, all of which should only contain one link. It seems that some of these products contain two or more links and I need some way of finding out which products have this problem. Ideally this would be in the form of a spreadsheet with SKU against the number of links, but if I could even find out where this information is stored in the database that would be helpful!

I tried exporting Downloadable Products via System...Import/Export...Dataflow Profiles but I can only export links_exist, links_purchased_separately and links_title, none of which enable me to find the number of links for a product.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest is by query

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) toomuch
FROM downloadable_link
GROUP BY product_id 
HAVING toomuch > 1
```

Comment: It's a pleasure!